# cocos2d-x Sprite::create("filename.png") returning null

Tags: cocos2d-x

For some reason this stopped working. It was working last time I was working on the project, but now it's not. I have double checked that `spaceCannonTitle.png` is included in the project. But it's throwing an exception on the setPosition line because title_sprite is null.

```
bool MenuScene::init()
{
    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();

    auto title_sprite = cocos2d::Sprite::create( "spaceCannonTitle.png" );
    title_sprite->setPosition( Point( visibleSize.width / 2 + origin.x, visibleSize.height - title_sprite->getContentSize( ).height ) );

    this->addChild( title_sprite );
    ...
}
```

EDIT: 
If I comment out the title_sprite, then it doesn't crash, but I don't see the menu and I get this error:

`libpng error: CgBI: unhandled critical chunk`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/15199). Apparently you have to go to Build Settings and set `Remove Text Metadata From PNG Files` to `NO`.

Comment: Also check to make sure the filename you are passing in matches the file in the project.